# char * to wchar_t * function implementation

Tags: c++, c, unicode

I'm trying to implement function, which will convert char* to wchar_t*. But problem is that, wprintf shows different result. What am I doing wrong?

```
wchar_t *toWchar(char *data)
{
    if(!data)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    int size = strlen(data);
    if(!size)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *temp = (char *)malloc(size * 2);
    if(!temp)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp[j++] = data[i];
        temp[j++] = '\0';
    }

    return (wchar_t *)temp;
}
```

EDIT:
the main function:

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t *temp = toWchar("hello, world!");
    if(temp)
        wprintf("%ls\n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What encodings are you using? What encoding for char, and what encoding for wchar_t? Your code could work if the char is ASCII. And do note that you need to add a null terminator.

Comment: Woohoo, so many problems! Could you give me some hints what to do? I'm just beginner in programming, I don't know which encoding I'm using.. if these info will help you, I'm using normal English language as locale on Linux box.

Comment: You need to work out what encodings you are using. Why do you want to convert to wchar_t? Why aren't you using library functions?

Comment: If you KNOW that your input is only ASCII, you could simply allocate a `wchar_t *temp = new wchar_t[size+1];` (or malloc with suitable cast, but since you posted in C++ as well, I prefer the C++ solution), and then just copy the char value into the corresponding position in the `temp`. Saves you having to cast so much too.

Comment: I'm trying to write my own, just for studying.

Comment: It's not ascii, it may contain some unicode (2 byte) characters too, that's why I want two byte long encoding. I though wchar_t was 2 bytes long, but seems it's 4 on my system. I need some solution..

Comment: No, you absolutely do not need a solution. Right now you need a problem. Since you don't know either of the encodings, you can't hope to solve a problem that cannot be stated.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is that, it works fine on Windows machine, but it fails on linux. Should I use short instead of wchar_t ? (I think I asked really dumb question.)

Comment: One last time. Step 1 is that you need to know both encodings. Once you know that, solution is easy.

Comment: Don't hard code the size of `wchar_t` as 2 when you use `malloc()`. That is a hint. In fact, I'll give you a reason why: `sizeof(wchar_t)==4` on many Linux machines. Whereas Windows uses UTF-16, those Linux machines use UTF-32. This isn't necessarily true for all Linux machines or Unix machines for that matter. Some may decide to use a strange Unicode variant of EBCDIC or even the Chinese GB18030 for the encoding of `wchar_t`. Bottom line: assume _nothing_ about `wchar_t`, including its size and character encoding. The best you can do is use its size to help you convert. :-)

Comment: See boost::nowide header only implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point;
gcc will give you platform dependent wchar type/size as follows:

```
echo "" | gcc -E - -dM | grep WCHAR

#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __WCHAR_MIN__ (-__WCHAR_MAX__ - 1)
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 4
```

[A resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) suggests:

"Both C and C++ introduced fixed-size character types char16_t and char32_t in the 2011 revisions of their respective standards to provide unambiguous representation of 16-bit and 32-bit Unicode transformation formats, leaving wchar_t implementation-defined."

Comment: damn.. I though wchar_t was 2 bytes :( how could I use platform independent encodings?

Comment: @user2399415 edited to suggest you different types: such as `char16_t` or `char32_t`

Comment: Thank you very much! jamesdlin's post are very useful too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few obvious problems:

1. You're not allocating space for a NUL-terminator.
2. You're assuming that `wchar_t` is 2 bytes, which isn't necessarily true.  On many Linux systems, it might represent a UTF-32 code unit, which is 4 bytes long.
3. You're assuming that you're using a little-endian architecture, which also isn't necessarily true (although it's likely to be true).
4. You're calling `wprintf()` on a `const char*` format string, but `wprintf()` expects a `const wchar_t*` argument.  The compiler should have generated an error about this. (Did you remember to add `#include <wchar.h>` (for C) or `#include <cwchar>` (for C++)?)

Assuming that this is meant to work only on ASCII inputs, you can fix these issues by doing:

```
int size = strlen(data) + 1 /* NUL */;
...

// Allocate a wchar_t buffer directly.
// Note that the cast below is necessary in C++ but not in C.
wchar *temp = (wchar_t *)malloc(size * sizeof *temp);
...
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    temp[j++] = data[i];
}
```

and then when you call `wprintf`, use:

```
wprintf(L"%ls\n", temp); // Note the L prefix to the string literal.
```

Also, don't forget to call `free(temp)` when you're done.

Comment: typo: `wchar *temp` -> `wchar_t* temp`

Comment: *Ahem*, I'm trying to convert one-byte characters to two-byte characters (I understand 'unicode' keyword like this.) e.g 'a' becomes 'a\x00' because some keywords that I'm using is two bytes long, it's not only ASCII :)

Comment: @user2399415: Your original code attempted to only pad characters with zero bytes, which would work only for ASCII characters.  If you need to handle other encodings, you will: 1. Figure out exactly *which* encoding(s) you're dealing with and 2. Write a decoder (or preferably use an existing library).

Comment: Thank you for your info, both, your and sgun's solutions are perfect. I have to study now. Hope you'll not get mad if I choose sgun's post acceptable :-)